# Will using Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC allow my web project to work on different database vendors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have been using asp.net MVC web application and Entity Framework with SQL Server 2008 R2. But now one of our clients requires us to use Oracle 10g database. So my question is what will happen if I do the following:-

1. I create the same tables that are already inside sql server , inside a new Oracle DB.
2. I create a new ADO.net Entity data model , and define the Oracle database instead of SQL Server 2008 R2. And map the oracle tables.

So I am assuming that Entity Framework 6 will generate the same `model.edmx` class regardless of the database vendor . And in this case can I re-use my application and run it on Oracle database ?

Is this the case, or there are more steps to follow , to be able to have my asp.net mvc 5 web application working on both SQL Server & Oracle databases without worrying about the database vendor ?
bearing in mind that i am not using stored procedures at all, and all my business logic is implemented inside my Controller and Model classes.

Thanks

Comment: In theory: yes. And in theory, there's no difference between theory and practice ....

Comment: Using the code-first approach makes this a bit simpler, the provider model works so well that over a few weekends we made a text file based implementation. Slow as you might expect and doesn't support the full ADO.Net vocabulary, but the app runs just the same, all we switch is the connection string!

Answer (score 3):

In theory, yes - Entity Framework "abstracts" away the underlying database - to a certain degree.

But in reality, different databases from different vendors are just different - often to the point where trying to support both (or multiple) simultaneously isn't practical.

My approach here would be:

- create the same table structure in Oracle as you have in SQL Server
- encapsulate the EDMX model and the database-specific features into a separate class library - one for SQL Server, one for Oracle
- put a database-independent layer on top of this (e.g. the "Repository Pattern" or other approaches)
- make sure no database-specific features "leak out" of this encapsulation layer
- configure your app so that either the SQL Server or the Oracle database core assembly will be loaded at startup

With such an approach, you should be able to handle both databases - not exactly switching at runtime, but you can configure one or the other to be used.

Comment: thanks for the reply, mainly in my situation i will create two EDMX files , but on each project i will have only have one of them. i do not need things to be very dynamic, so each project can either run under Sql server or under Oracle DB . but my original question was mainly if EF help in achieving this feature. so that my application can run on Oracle or on Sql serverdepend of the customer preferences... and i do not need to do extra work , so i only need to create the tables on the required DB vendor, then create the edmx file..

Comment: @johnG: if you don't ever use any database- or vendor-specific features, then yes - writing your code using Entity Framework should work just fine against SQL Server and Oracle in that case.

Comment: i think that i am not using any DB vendor specific features, for example i am not calling any stored procedures , or calling DB functions or views ,, what other features i could be using and i am not aware of ?

Answer (score 1):

I once used Oracle 11 in place of SQL Server and found that Oracle 11 does not have a provision for Identity column and I had to implement the same using  a trigger and I had to auto generate Identity while inserting as EF was not picking up Id value generated by the trigger. So ideally there shouldn't be any change but practically there are a lot of subtle changes required.

Also take the example of boolean field which is present in SQL Server but not in Oracle.

**--Revised--** 
Further Reading-

1. [Map multiple databases to EF](http://www.infoq.com/articles/multiple-databases)
2. [Changes in EF required for working with Oracle](http://blog.devart.com/set-identity-and-computed-properties-in-entity-framework-without-triggers.html)
3. [ODP.NET provider](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html)

Comment: so you mean that Oracle DB does not support boolean data type ? i think both sql server & Oracle support Bit data type which i use to store true/false data type. but i am using identity column in all our tables and this might be causing problems ...??

Comment: Oracle 11g does not have support for boolean data type , so you will be forced to use bit data type as you mentioned.And yes you understood correctly that autoincrement of identity columns is not present in Oracle 11 g. Oracle 12c supports both boolean as well as autoincrement of identity columns.

Comment: so in my case our client is using Oracle 10g , which does not suport auto increment ID filed. so in this way what i can do to handle this ?

Comment: @johnG I was also working on a project which had Oracle 11g and I was forced to write code and generate edmx specifically for Oracle. The problem only arises when you intend to use the same project for both Oracle and SQL Server.Please check my edit to the answer.

Comment: thanks for your helpful answer , but how did you manage the auto generated ID in Oracle 11i ? as i did not understand what do u exactly mean by  ".... and I had to auto generate Identity while inserting as EF was not picking up Id value generated by the trigger"

Comment: I took max(Id) from entities and added 1  to it. I assigned this new value to the soon to be inserted entity.

Comment: @johnG I hope this answers your question that it is not that straightforward to switch between databases but with proper design of data access, it can be made relatively less painful.